# Resharper IQuotedValue

Tags: c#, resharper

I have this variable in C# which is part of a resharper plugin I am creating to throw a warning on all quoted values (not just strings).

```
                var sourceFile = _process.SourceFile;
                var file = sourceFile.GetPsiServices().Files.GetDominantPsiFile<CSharpLanguage>(sourceFile);

                if (file != null)
                {
                    var highlights = new List<HighlightingInfo>();

                    var stringHighlight = new RecursiveElementProcessor<IQuotedValue>(declaration =>
                    {
                        var docRange = declaration.GetDocumentRange();
                            highlights.Add(new HighlightingInfo(docRange, new MakeMethodVirtualSuggestion("Warning...")));
                    });

                   file.ProcessDescendants(stringHighlight);
                   commiter(new DaemonStageResult(highlights));
                }
```

It works when using IMethodDeclaration but can't figure out how to pick up an IQuotedValue value.  Is the RecursiveElementProcessor the wrong thing to use in this situation?  Any and all help is appreciated greatly been trying to figure this out for many many hours now.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: What quoted values, other than strings, are you looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`IQuotedValue` is a XAML element - it doesn't get used in the C# syntax tree. The best thing to do is look for elements of `ILiteralExpression`, or `ICSharpLiteralExpression`, and then look at the `Literal` property to see what it is - `true`, `false` a number, character or string.

Comment: Thanks citizenmatt, I got this working not long ago before I saw this. I'm using `ICSharpLiteralExpression` which has `IsStringLiteral()` that returns true or false.